# Populating Items in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two dropdown menus on an access form one for the main category and one for a subcategory. Based upon what you select in the main category, the sub-category dropdown should populate accordingly.

Now based on whats selected in the sub-category, a textbox should then populate.

Its been awhile since I've done any work with SQL and even then I didn't use MS access frequently so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? My advice would be two snippets of VBA code. In the after update event for your main category, you will set the values or row source for your sub-category. In the after-update event for your sub-category, you will set the value of the text box.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have two comboboxes, Combobox1 and Combobox2, and a textbox, set them up like this:
Make the Combobox2 properties like this (change to suit your needs)

```
Row Source Type = Table/Query
Row Source = SELECT <Fields> FROM <Table> WHERE Crit_Field=[Combobox1]
```

Combobox1 should have and a Sub for the Change event which tells Combobox2 to populate:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
    Me.Combobox2.Requery
End Sub
```

Combobox2 should also have a Sub for its Change event which tells the textbox to populate:

```
Private Sub Combobox2_Change()
    ' Stuff that populates the textbox
End Sub
```